# Tag Menu items based on their categories

Tags: categories, menus, tags

Suppose I have a site with this menu-structure:

> food
>
> - banana
> - carrot
> - apple
> - lettuce

where the fruit-items belong to `fruit` and the vegetables belongs to `vegetable`. Now ultimately I’d like to colour the item’s appearance according to their categories. For that to work, it would suffice to add `class=fruit` to all members of `fruit` and the same correspondingly for the vegetables. How would I go about to do that?

Comment: look the HTMl source of the page, in almost all themes, the CSS classes are already in place to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

From the WP-Admin.

Click on Appearance > Menus

In the top right, click "Screen Options"

Select (check) "CSS Classes"

Then you will have added the optional "CSS CLASSES" to each menu item.[image]